# Regular Expression question for occurence check :

Tags: java, regex

Check if a number n occurs n times and that too consecutively in a string.

For example : 
String x = "33322"
Case 1 : If int N = 3;

Check if 3 occurs 3 times consecutively in "33322".

Here 3 occurs 3 times consecutively in "33322". Hence, we return true.

Case 2 : If int N = 2;

Check if 2 occurs 2 times consecutively in "33322".

Here 2 occurs 2 times consecutively in "33322". Hence, we return true.

I have tried various Regular Expression but may be because of not being very thorough, I am not clear what expression will help me in achieving this task. I have tried with the given Regular Expression pattern 
: "^["+N+"]{"+(N-1)+"}("+N+")$".

But for this the output is coming false, whereas it should have been true as you can see that the number 3 clearly is occurring 3 times in the above example.

Here I am looking for a Regular Expression that can match with all possible values for N.

N can be from 2-500

Comment: Why not use `"(" + N + "){" + N + "}"`?

Comment: What if you 3333 in your first scenario, is it exactly 3 times or at least 3 times?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Should be true, because it's three times 3 consecutively.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This doesn't work for N >= 10, because you need parenthesis around the number.

Comment: In case you don't want to use RegEx: `System.out.println(x.contains(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, String.valueOf(n)))));` Otherwise you could use: `System.out.println(x.matches(".*(" + n + "){" + n + "}.*"));`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex `.*(N){N}.*` when using the `matches` method of the `String` class or alternatively the `(N){N}` regex when using the `find` method of a `Matcher`. N is the number you are looking for.

**EDIT:** Added a Java example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc10101010101010101010xyz";
    System.out.println(checkOccurrence(s, 10)); // true
    s = "abc33322xyz";
    System.out.println(checkOccurrence(s, 3)); // true
    System.out.println(checkOccurrence(s, 2)); // true
}

private static boolean checkOccurrence(String text, int number) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(" + number + "){" + number + "}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    return m.find();
}
```

Comment: Any string that starts with any characters, contains n times the number n consecutively and then ends with any characters, doesn't it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Doesn't matter how much you match. This regex works when using `matches()`. If using `find()`, then the two `.*` are redundant. Since question didn't specify whether `matches()` or `find()` will be used, this answer is valid, but I would rather have given regex without the `.*` and added that you must use `find()`. +1 from me.

Comment: The `.*` are necessary if you use `matches`.

Comment: Since question is about having an `int N`, I'd suggest writing the code as a reusable method, e.g. `boolean checkOccurrence(String text, int n) { ... }`, then call that method from `main`. That way, you will give the full solution, since you now have to *build* the regex too, which is needed by the question. --- In that method, you can choose to use `find()`, so the `.*` aren't necessary, which would be my preference, but it's your answer, so your choice, of course, though it would perform better that way (since it won't have to check rest of input). ;-)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your suggestion. I thought it wouldn't be too hard for the OP to implement that method by himself, but it makes the answer better, indeed.